# Wacom Intuos S 2 button mapping problems

Tags: 16.04, tablet, wacom

I have recently purchased a Wacom Intuos S 2 tablet, and it has been working swimmingly. The only real problems that I have had are with the buttons on the tablet itself.

I've searched and searched again, and although I have found directions to map the buttons, none of these articles (that I've read) address my problem. I can map the buttons by using

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad" Button [1, 2, 3] "ctrl z"
```

The main problem is that only buttons 1 through 3 actually have an effect on the pad, and even then, buttons 2 and 3 only rout to the top left, whereas button 1 is the bottom left. Button four doesn't even do anything, I just get the error

```
Unsupported offset into 'Wacom Button Actions' property.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: The first problem has been solved, thanks! The last and only other problem I have is this: When I turn off the computer or unplug the tablet, all of this data is lost and I have to reenter the button assignments. Again, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the buttons are numbered 1,3,8,9. Please see: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Consumer_Tablet_ExpressKey_Mapping_Issue

Comment: The wiki has moved, new URL: https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Consumer-Tablet-ExpressKey-Mapping-Issue